# Using Base class Static const variable for constructing Base Class, Can I do it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, constructor, constants

I have a base and derived class. The base class constructors have some static const variables. Is it okay to use it in derived class constructor to construct base class variable??

an example code will be

```
  //Base.hpp    
  class Base {
   public:
        Base(int value_, long sizee_);
   private:
        int value;
        int sizee;
   protected:
        static const int ONE = 1;
        static const int TWO = 2;
        static const long INT_SIZE = (long)sizeof(int);
        static const long LONG_SIZE = (long)sizeof(long);
  };

  //Base.cpp
  Base::Base(int value_,int sizee_):value(value_),sizee(sizee_) {
  }

  //Derived.hpp
  class Derived: class Base {
    public:
          Derived();
  };

  //Derived.cpp
  Derived::Derived():Base(ONE+TWO,INT_SIZE+LONG_SIZE) {
  }
```

Here ONE,TWO,INT_SIZE,LONG_SIZE are base class static variables, I will using it to construct the base class itself. Is this approach fine? Please advice.

Comment: You don't need INT_SIZE and LONG_SIZE. Just say `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(long)` where you need to.

Comment: Yeah, but I use it too many times in the program, so I thought, would save an value in the variable. I thought I am avoiding too may function calls, but wait a sec, sizeofint is inline or wat?

Comment: It's a compile time constant, there's no run-time overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. By the time you create a `Dervide` object, all `static` members are initialized. That is, unless you have `static` `Derived` objects.

Comment: sure, thanks, one more question will be, if I use enum, would it be still be same as static?

Comment: @howtechstuffworks no, `enum` is not the same as `static`. But in this case, you could put `ONE` and `TWO` in an enum, and it does look cleaner.

Comment: Cool... One more thing is, I have some function like read((char*)&ONE, sizeof(int)). I assume enum does not have address, will it work in these cases? or static int is the way to go? In the read function, I need to pass the pointer, so the function will copy everything bit by bit and store in a file. WIll enum work or static const is the way to go? (I am assuming static const have address, please correct me if I am wrong). thanks!

Comment: @howtechstuffworks you can assign enum values to variables. Just as in your case, your variable is `ONE`. You can say `x = ONE` and pass it as read((char*)&x, sizeof(int)), but I gotta tell you, this seems fishy (casting the address to a char*).

Comment: Nope, its not user defined function. its a fstream.h function, read(). Thanks for your inputs